# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sqlldr": error=2, A file or directory in the path name does not exist

Tags: java, oracle, aix

I try to use SQL*Loader import data to Oracle. The concrete method is that I make a Java class to call "sqlldr". There is a excerpt of my method as follows:

```
public class SqlldrImportDataFile {
  public String executeImport(String user, String password, String database,String fileRoute, String ctlfileName, 
        String logsRoute,String logfileName) {
    InputStream ins = null;
    String dos = "sqlldr " + user + "/" + password + "@" + database + " control=" + fileRoute + ctlfileName + " log=" + logsRoute + logfileName;
    String returnCode = "0";
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(dos);
        ins = process.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String msg = new String(line.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
        }

        int exitValue = process.waitFor();

        process.getOutputStream().close();
        reader.close();
        ins.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "-1";
    }
    return returnCode;
}
```

}

Howerver,there is a problem when I run application which is "`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sqlldr": error=2, A file or directory in the path name does not exist.`" The detail error information as follows:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sqlldr": error=2, A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.processException(ProcessBuilder.java:489)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:468)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:604)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:442)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:339)
at com.sdb.bbcp.common.SqlldrImportDataFile.executeImport(SqlldrImportDataFile.java:188)
at com.sdb.bbcp.common.SqlldrImportDataFile.execute(SqlldrImportDataFile.java:80)
at com.sdb.common.flow.SDBEMPFlow.execute(SDBEMPFlow.java:175)
at com.ecc.emp.flow.Operation.execute(Operation.java:96)
at com.ecc.emp.flow.EMPBusinessLogic.execute(EMPBusinessLogic.java:89)
at com.ecc.emp.processor.EMPBusinessLogicCaller.execute(EMPBusinessLogicCaller.java:112)
at com.sdb.common.flow.SDBEMPFlow.execute(SDBEMPFlow.java:175)
at com.ecc.emp.flow.Operation.execute(Operation.java:96)
at com.ecc.emp.flow.EMPBusinessLogic.execute(EMPBusinessLogic.java:89)
at com.ecc.emp.processor.EMPBusinessLogicCaller.execute(EMPBusinessLogicCaller.java:112)
at com.sdb.common.flow.SDBEMPFlow.execute(SDBEMPFlow.java:175)
at com.ecc.emp.flow.Operation.execute(Operation.java:96)
at com.ecc.emp.flow.EMPBusinessLogic.execute(EMPBusinessLogic.java:89)
at com.sdb.bbcp.communication.BBCPTCPIPRequestService.handleRequest(BBCPTCPIPRequestService.java:190)
at com.sdb.bbcp.communication.BBCPTCPIPServiceServlet.processNewPackage(BBCPTCPIPServiceServlet.java:505)
at com.ecc.emp.tcpip.TCPIPService.processNewPackage(TCPIPService.java:652)
at com.ecc.emp.tcpip.TCPIPService.newPackageReceived(TCPIPService.java:567)
at com.ecc.emp.tcpip.SocketProcessThread.runTask(SocketProcessThread.java:127)
at com.ecc.emp.tcpip.SocketProcessThread.run(SocketProcessThread.java:107)
at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1061)
at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:575)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

I search too much resoures from Internet.And I check environment of server,execute command by writting "sqlldr" to shell...But it until error.

- User: username
- Server: AIX 7.1.0.0
- $ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/../product/10.2.0
- $PATH=.:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:.
- chown -R username /oracle/
- User Groups: staff system dba

---

So what should I do?
P.S.  The applicaton work normally on our other machines.

Comment: Does any of the strings passed to the command contain spaces?

Comment: That ORACLE_HOME looks odd, does it really have `..` or have you masked part of the path? Can you run sqlldr from the command line?

Comment: Don't misunderstand it. The path just be omitted whith `..`. Sqlldr can work on command line nomally.

Comment: Try full path: `String dos = "export ORACLE_HOME=/your/secret_path/; $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlldr"+...`

Comment: Correction: `String dos = "export ORACLE_HOME=/your/secret_path/; $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlldr"+...; dos= "sh -c '"+dos"'"`

Comment: I see, I'll try tomorrow.